# "Aged" vs. "Aging" to describe someone's age

Tags: word-choice

I'm just wondering if we can also use the word ***aging*** when describing someone's age as in this example:

> The study included participants ***aging*** 20 to 50.

Comment: The only word to use in that sentence is aged, not ageing. Ageing is the process of becoming older.

Comment: You just need to look up the word *ageing* in a good dictionary.

Comment: Note the different spellings in the UK (ageing) and the USA (aging).

Comment: You can use "aging" if the study took 30 years.

Comment: The study included participants between 20 and 50 years of age.

Answer (score 1):

"AGE"- Be it 'verb' or 'noun' embodies a sense of becoming or being grown up in terms of time from birth or beginning marked by changes may be inward or outward or both applicable to living as well as nonliving.

AGE as noun: Length of time a being or
             thing existed.

AGE as verb without object: To grow old. 
            (He is ageing rapidly)

AGE as verb with object: to make old.
             ( Fear aged him)

Ageing/aged : Participle ,gerund / past
              participle

" Age" embodies this sense of progression or Advancement and its     "-ing" form further enhances it and can never mean anything other than conveying something happening or going on. The word-meaning puts a serious limitation on the present participle use of "age" and binds it with the continuing sense only.

So we may write:-

1) Participants aged 20 to 50

2) of the age ranging/spanning from 20 to 50.

AGEING IS A PROCESS , AGED ITS POINTS.
If ageing is a flowing stream, aged  is to desceibe its innumerable landings

Comment: Typos: *aging* and *describe*

Answer (score 1):

Why not say "The study included participants **between the ages of** 20 and 50 years old"?

Comment: This is a commonsense (and widely used) wording. On close inspection, it seems somewhat ambiguous with regard to whether 20 and 50 are included in the range or sit just outside it at each end, but that shortcoming can be remedied by specifying the endpoints that _are_ included (either "20 and 50" or "21 and 49") and adding the word _inclusive_ at the end of the sentence.

Comment: That may be an alternative, but you haven't actually addressed this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

"Aged" means "old"; "aging" means "getting old" (but not quite there yet).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this puzzle we need to fix your example, because it is missing a word at the end. We often leave it out, because we consider it obvious from the context. The word is `years`.

> The study included participants aged 20 to 50 years.
>
> The study included participants aging 20 to 50 years.

Now it is obvious that only the first one is correct, because in the first example the participants at the time of the study have aged a number of years equal to their age. In the second sentence however, the participants are getting 20 to 50 years older during the study.

Probably when you like the "aging" word, what you are really thinking of is a sentence like

> The study included participants of different ages **ranging** from 20 to 50 years of age.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Aging is a process, and is therefor without meaning if you put a number to it.  You need to use "aged".  Although grammatically correct however, this use implies an active "aging" process as well.  Don't even use the word, it sounds better to phrase it: "The study included participants 20 to 50 year old."

Answer (score 0):

Aging is what is happening. Aged is what has already happened.

I would use ages ("ages 20-to-50" or "ages 20-to-50-years-old") because you are referring to plural participants.

Or you could write, "ranging in age from 20-to-50." Or, "between 20-and-50." In that case, though, now that I think about it, "from 20-to-50" might be better because you want to include 20 and 50, not just the ages in-between. I wouldn't use any of these in this paragraph though, because I don't think they are as succinct or elegant.

You could also skip it altogether and just use participants ("participants 20-to-50" or "participants 20-to-50-years-old"). If you want the word age in there though, then I would go with ages.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the word aging in a sentence but when talking about a short term research project then I would say no because it has nothing to do with how they age.

Answer (score -1):

The more I think about this, the less happy I am with a simplistic answer.

Many verbs are used in the middle voice:

> We weighed the parcel.
>
> *The parcel weighed 3 kg.*

And the ing-form may in some cases be used correspondingly:

> *A parcel weighing 3kg was sent to the station.*

Here, the verb **age** isn't used in the middle voice with the sense of 'be of the age', but the ed-form (though not the ing-form) *is* used with this sense:

> *I age / He aged 42.
>
> A man aged 42 (= A man who is 42 years old)
>
> *A man ageing 42

I'd say that etically, the unacceptable 'ageing' would indeed be the expected choice here.

Comment: Participants aged vs participants aging:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=participants+aging%2C+participants+aged&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparticipants%20aged%3B%2Cc0

Comment: 'Aged' - past participle - is the only form that makes sense here. It's true that I'm ageing, but the process of ageing over a time-span of 65 years means that I'm aged 65.

Comment: I'd say that 'I am aged ...' is an idiomatic form rather than a 'form that makes sense'. We don't say 'The bowl was weighted 8 ounces'.

Comment: How can a person be *aging* between 20 and 25? I am aging now as of this moment, and hopefully I will reach my next birthday but I wouldn't say *I'm aging 55*. The survey (if this sentence were one) would be asking people of different ages within that range, someone who's 21 and another who's 24. Yes they were in the process of aging, but the moment they were questioned they were at that specific age.

Comment: Edwin, it may be an idiom, but it's a well-established one. "John Doe, aged 52, was arrested at the scene". The fact that we don't use "weighted" the same way doesn't undermine that.

Comment: `He aged 42` does not sound correct. `He aged visibly while we looked` or `While in space he aged 42 years while his brother aged 84 years`

Comment: @David Garner It's an invalid comparison. _Police arrested him ..._ <==> _He was arrested at the scene ..._ is the active <==> passive transformation. Here, 'I am aged' is not a passive (which is only available for wines etc). // Idioms are by definition well established. But idiosyncratic in form.

Comment: @Mary-Lou A I'm saying that 'A man ageing 42' **is** unacceptable, but might justifiably be expected by someone not familiar with the quirky way English actually works (hence the 'etic'). Compare 'A man batting .235' (and presumably still batting), not "a man batted .235'.

Comment: The 'idiomatic aspect' merely trots out a paraphrase of 'That's just the way we say it in English'. My last 3 examples spell this out (I assume you know what the asterisk means). I was concerned that the first two comments (1) directed OP to 'look in a dictionary' which doesn't tell them that 'participants aging 20 to 50' is not idiomatic (in fact, I'd say unacceptable) and (2) didn't reassure OP that their request probably makes more sense than the actual English we use does.

Comment: How is 'You've approached the question from a "logical/semantic" standpoint and **appeared to have ignored the idiomatic aspect**.' compatible with << Here, the verb _age_ isn't used in the middle voice with the sense of 'be of the age', but the ed-form (**though not the ing-form**) is used with this sense:

*I age / He aged 42.

A man aged 42 (= A man who is 42 years old)

***A man ageing 42'** >>? Your criticism appears to be ill-founded.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, it's possible to view "I am aged 65" as an active-passive transformation of "Time has aged me 65 [years]. Compare "My wife painted the kitchen blue" with "The kitchen is painted blue."

Comment: An active-passive transformation there would be "My wife painted the kitchen blue" <==> "The kitchen **was** painted blue." I'm not saying it hasn't arisen in such a way, but 'I'm aged 65' is a stranger beast.

Comment: OK, Edwin, I can see I won't win this one!

Answer (score -1):

Ageing (Aging)- the process of becoming older and represents the build up of changes on the specific person

source- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageing

Aged-Growing older and states specified length of time; of a specified age.